# regarding encryption method

Tags: c++, symbian

i am using encrypt function of cryptography api(fun declared as virtual)

```
//fun declaration
TBool EncryptL(const TDesC8 &aInput, TDes8 &aOutput);

//function calling
TBuf8<10> text;
TBuf8<10> cipher;
text.Copy(_L("Hello"));
iEncryptor.EncryptL(text,cipher); it shows error expression syntax error

//fun definition
TBool CRSAAlgo::EncryptL(const TDesC8 &aInput,TDes8 &aOutput) 
{
    if(iEncryptor)
    {
        TInt len = iEncryptor->MaxInputLength();
    }
}
```

i want to know what is exact problem

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here, the reason your compiler complains is that you are using iEncryptor as an object or a reference, while it probably is a C++ pointer.

To move to the next stage, try using:

iEncryptor->EncryptL(text,cipher);

Answer (score -1):

As you did not post the exact error message you get from the compiler I have to guess.

I assume the problem is that the *EncryptL* function you show expects to get arguments of type *TDesC8* and you pass a *TBuf8<10>* to it. Unless *TDesC8* were a typedef to *TBuf8<10>* these are different and therefore for the compiler incompatible types.

Ypou are also using *iEncryptor* once as a pointer: *iEncryptor->MaxInputLength();* and at the location where you see the error as an object: *iEncryptor.EncryptL(text,cipher);*. Only one form can be correct. As we don't have more code from you I don't know which, but given the fact that the latter has the error I suspect the latter.